# Hex value in string conversion

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, stringstream

I have a C++ script which involves string representations of would-be hexadecimal numbers. In a later portion of the script, I would like to convert these would-be hexadecimal numbers into doubles for some arithmetic in base 10. To try to make this conversion, I use a function.

```
double MyFunction(string input)
{
double Number;
stringstream ss(input);
ss >> hex >> Number;
return Number;
}
```

When my script runs, it seems the resulting converted string is only considered as a decimal number. If the original string was "fc" or "b5", it says the converted number is -9.25596e+061. But if the string was "33" (which is supposed to be 0x33), it views it as decimal 33. I have tried it without the ">> hex" and with adding a "0x" prefix to the string before conversion (since the compile seems to understand 0xF just as it would 16), but no such luck.

I understand the computer stores everything as binary and that the base a number is viewed at is not stored, but I simply do not understand what is wrong here. Why does it seemingly insist upon reading the string in base 10 and disregarding any instance of A-F?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hex manipulator only works for integral types like int. First input the hexadecimal string into an integer and then convert that to a double:

```
double MyFunction(string input)
{
    int Number; // Notice now Number is an integer
    stringstream ss(input);
    ss >> hex >> Number; 
    return Number; // This should convert Number to a double via promotion
}
```